# remove character on the last line that specific word appears

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

we have the following file example

we want to remove the `,`  character on the last line that `topic` word exists

```
more file

{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":84,"replicas":[1006,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":85,"replicas":[1001,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":86,"replicas":[1002,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":87,"replicas":[1003,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":88,"replicas":[1004,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":89,"replicas":[1005,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":90,"replicas":[1006,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":91,"replicas":[1001,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":92,"replicas":[1002,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":93,"replicas":[1003,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":94,"replicas":[1004,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":95,"replicas":[1005,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":96,"replicas":[1006,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":97,"replicas":[1001,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":98,"replicas":[1002,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":99,"replicas":[1003,1002]},
```

expected output

```
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":84,"replicas":[1006,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":85,"replicas":[1001,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":86,"replicas":[1002,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":87,"replicas":[1003,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":88,"replicas":[1004,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":89,"replicas":[1005,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":90,"replicas":[1006,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":91,"replicas":[1001,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":92,"replicas":[1002,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":93,"replicas":[1003,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":94,"replicas":[1004,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":95,"replicas":[1005,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":96,"replicas":[1006,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":97,"replicas":[1001,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":98,"replicas":[1002,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":99,"replicas":[1003,1002]}
```

we try to removed the character `,` from the the last line that contain `topic` word as the following sed cli but this syntax not renewed the `,`

```
sed -i '${s/,[[:blank:]]*$//}' file
```

---

sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: It looks like the capitols letters are broken on your keyboard or phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have control M characters in your Input_file then remove them by doing:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following once. From your question what I understood is you want to remove comma from very last line which has string `topic` in it, if this is the case then I am coming up with `tac` + `awk` solution here.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '/topic/ && ++count==1{sub(/,$/,"")} 1' | 
tac
```

Once you are happy with above results then append `> temp && mv temp Input_file` to above command too, to save output into Input_file itself.

***Explanation:***

A`tac` will read Input_file from bottom line to first line then passing it's output to awk where I am checking if first occurrence of topic is coming remove comma from last and rest of lines simply print then passing this output to tac again to make Input_file in original form again.

Comment: I think OP has `\r\n` line-endings and I have no idea of the awk version.

Comment: You have the same problem I had, consider `,\r` -> `\r`. Your solution worked with that.

Comment: `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file` ??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ahh thank you, you GEM in my defense it was 4 am in morning :) :) I corrected it now. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the address `$` (last line):

```
sed '$s/,$//' file
```

Comment: I test it , but its not removed the ","

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{if(NR>1)print p;p=$0}END{sub(/,$/,"",p);print p}' file
```

Output:

```
...
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":98,"replicas":[1002,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":99,"replicas":[1003,1002]}
```

Comment: I test it , but its not removed the  ","

Comment: Probably Windows line-endings (`\r\n` as opposed to `\n` used in for example Linux) then. You could: `awk '{if(NR>1)print p;p=$0}END{sub(/,\r$/,"\r",p);print p}' file` ie. replace `,\r` with `\r`.